# get dbus.Struct properties

Tags: python, dbus

I'm trying to write a notification script using python-dbus.
How can I get properties from a dbus.Struct object?
For example if I print it out as string, it is 
dbus.Struct((dbus.String(u'msg_subject:Re: email subject'),), signature=None)
I need to get the inner string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `dbus.Struct` inherits from tuple, so you should be able to do this:

```
>>> msg = dbus.Struct((dbus.String(u'msg_subject:Re: email subject'),), signature=None)
>>> msg[0]
dbus.String(u'msg_subject:Re: email subject')
```

Comment: thanks! that worked. I can print the inner string as str(msg[0])